# Отрисовка графиков через django-google-charts

Tags: python, django, google-chart

Использую эту статью на хабре https://m.habr.com/ru/post/126704/

В функции возникает ошибка name 'Count' is not defined

Модель:

```
class paidparking(models.Model):
    adress = models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Адрес парковки')
    carnumber = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Номер автомобиля')
    amountoftime = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество времени')
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Электронный адрес',null=True,blank=True )
    datetimepaidparking = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата и время оплаты')
    expirationdate = models.DateField(null=True,verbose_name='Дата начала срока действия')
    expirationtime = models.TimeField(null=True,verbose_name='Время начала срока действия')
    enddateandtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Окончание срока действия')
```

Функция:

```
def view_func(request):
    start_date = '30 апреля 2021 г.'
    end_date = '5 мая 2021 г'

    queryset = paidparking.objects.all()
    # считаем количество платежей...
    qsstats = QuerySetStats(queryset, date_field='datetime', aggregate=Count('id'))
    # ...в день за указанный период
    values = qsstats.time_series(start_date, end_date, interval='days')

    return render_to_response('template.html', {'values': values})
```

Comment: [там](https://github.com/PetrDlouhy/django-qsstats-magic) Count('id') по-умолчанию, попробуйте просто без него?

Comment: qsstats = QuerySetStats(queryset, date_field='datetime') Получаю ошибку: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'